# Extract difference in consecutive values for MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, sql

| Name | Date | Hours | Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mills | 2022-07-17 | 23 | 12 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 00 | 15 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 01 | 20 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 02 | 22 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 03 | 25 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 04 | 20 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 05 | 22 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 06 | 25 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 00 | 15 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 01 | 20 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 02 | 22 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 03 | 25 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 04 | 20 |

My current input table stores information for counts recorded in each hour of the day consecutively. I need to extract the difference in values for consecutive counts but I'm having trouble doing it since I'm forced to use MySQL 5.7.

I have written the query as follows:

```
SET @cnt := 0;
SELECT Name, Date, Hours, Count, (@cnt := @cnt - Count) AS DiffCount
FROM Hourly
ORDER BY Date;
```

which is not  giving  exact results.

I expect to have the following output:

| Name | Date | Hours | Count | Diff |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mills | 2022-07-17 | 23 | 12 | 0 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 00 | 15 | 3 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 01 | 20 | 5 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 02 | 22 | 2 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 03 | 25 | 3 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 04 | 20 | 5 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 05 | 22 | 2 |
| Mills | 2022-07-18 | 06 | 25 | 3 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 00 | 15 | 0 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 01 | 20 | 5 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 02 | 22 | 2 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 03 | 25 | 3 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 04 | 20 | 5 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 05 | 22 | 2 |
| MIKE | 2022-07-18 | 06 | 25 | 3 |

Please suggest what I'm missing.

Comment: What version of `MySQL` you are using

Comment: version : 5.7.38

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **MySQL 5.7** you can update your variable inline in order to contain your updated value of "*Count*". Since when the value of "*Name*" changes you need to reset your variable, you can use another variable that contains the previous "*Name*" value. Then you use an [`IF`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/flow-control-functions.html#function_if) function to check:

- if your previous name is equal to your current name
- then take the difference in counts
- else assign 0

It would be combined with the [`ABS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) function, which applies the absolute value on the difference.

```
SET @cnt  := NULL;
SET @name := NULL;

SELECT Date,
       Hours,
       ABS(IF(@name = Name, 
              @cnt := @cnt - Count,
              0)                    ) AS DiffCount,
       (@name := Name)                AS Name,
       (@cnt := Count)                AS Count
FROM tab
ORDER BY Name DESC,
         Date, 
         Hours;
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6y8QNRveDpp1UxD7Wfno5s/6).

---

In **MySQL 8.0** you can use a window fuction like [`LAG`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_lag) to get your output smoothly. It would be combined with:

- [`ABS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_abs) that applies the absolute value on the difference,
- [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) employed for removing the first null value.

```
SELECT *, 
       COALESCE(ABS(
           Count - LAG(Count) OVER(
                       PARTITION BY Name
                       ORDER     BY Date, Hours
                   )
       ), 0) AS Diff 
FROM tab
ORDER BY Name DESC, 
         Date, 
         Hours
```

Check the demo [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6y8QNRveDpp1UxD7Wfno5s/5).

Comment: Now  I add another name  in the Name  column. it is  calculating the all counts

Comment: Can you update your post with the corresponding updated input and expected output?

Comment: I have  added the new  edit please check

Comment: How do you compute `Diff = 3` for the first MIKE's record: `MIKE  2022-07-18  00  15  3`?

Comment: Sorry I have  modified  now

Comment: Check the updated answer, does it satisfy your requirements?

Comment: checking  lemon in my code

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
SET @count=(select Count_ from Hourly order by Name,Date_,Hours LIMIT 1);
Set @Name=(select Name from Hourly order by Name,Date_,Hours LIMIT 1);

select  Name,Date_,Hours,Count_,
ABS(curr_count-lag_count) as DiffCount
From
(
  select Name,Date_,Hours,Count_, 
  Case When @Name = Name Then @count Else Count_ End as lag_count
  , @count:=Count_ curr_count, @Name:=Name
  From Hourly order by Name,Date_,Hours
) D
Order By Name,Date_,Hours;
```

See a demo from ***[db-fiddle.](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LRJ9zZao4Tt4AUfAt7KSM/3)***

Comment: Updated according to the new posted sample data (handle multiple names)

Comment: In this solution there may be some issues... check the fiddle updated with more data >> https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LRJ9zZao4Tt4AUfAt7KSM/5.

Comment: @lemon, I already updated the answer according to that, about 30 mins ago

Comment: @lemon Yes I know that you are trying to help, and thank you for that :) but what is the problem of the new query?

Comment: Basically all MIKE's Diff values are set to 0. There may be some problems in the ordering of your records in your subquery: this may set you on the right track to solve the issue.

Comment: @lemon This is the updated query, https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2LRJ9zZao4Tt4AUfAt7KSM/3   kindly check it, it gives the correct expected output.

Comment: Yes, this definitely works better!